# Changing the attribute of the HTML tag using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change the attribute of an `<a>` tag using jQuery but it's not working. I am trying to change the `src` attribute of the `<a>` tag from `www.google.com` to `www.somewebsite.com`. Can anyone please tell me where I am getting it wrong.

```
<p class="form-row text-varient">
    <label class="checkbox">
        Some text here
        <a target="_blank" href="http://google.com">Link Text</a>
    </label>
</p>
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".text-varient").find("a").attr("href", "http://www.somewebsite.com/");
});
```

Comment: Where does the `.terms` come from? It's not visible in your provided HTML

Comment: Where is the `.terms` element? The only reason this code wouldn't work is if that element is not in the source.

Comment: Do you have an element with class `terms`?

Comment: Its not terms its .text-varient

Comment: Well, given your update, the code works  fine: http://jsfiddle.net/qhr1edkf/. If you're still having issues, check the console for errors.

Comment: Is your anchor tag(`<a>`) you want to change the very first anchor tag inside `label`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $(".checkbox").find('a').attr("href", 'http://www.somewebsite.com');
 });
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zhts44tn/4/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<p class="form-row text-varient">
<label class="checkbox">
    Some text here
    <a target="_blank" href="http://google.com">Link Text</a>
</label>
</p>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".checkbox a").attr("href", "http://www.somewebsite.com");

});



</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but this will change all the attributes of the <a> tag in the website i want this specific attribute to be changed